# HTML/CSS, integrating a slider template

Tags: html, css

I want to integrate this slider into my web page:

Template: codepen.io/suez/pen/ByvKXE

(I have the permission), but it is using a css rules that contains "body" and "html" selectors which ruins my web page and contradicts with my own CSS stylesheet. these lines of code from the template:

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  background: #000;
}
```

How can i do it without affecting my web page?

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve then?

Comment: I want to find the alternative CSS code that does the same job without using the "body" and "html" selectors

Comment: What about this: https://codepen.io/justdan/pen/MBrGzw

Comment: Not working, removing them makes it very non responsive

Comment: That's because when you take away the `height: 100%;`, you'll lose some mobile styles because of the screen size change. This is now responsive similar to the one you first provided: https://codepen.io/justdan/pen/MBrGzw